# My bonsai, a pomegranate, has already lost all its leaves, it’s getting a little growth, but what can I do to help it?

Tags: bonsai

It’s still alive, the fiber just under the bark is alive/green, but the only new growth has died and the newest is dying. The fiber of one of the roots coming up is losing its green, so I think it’s dying too. I moved it outside and it i a sunnier spot and I’m watering it when the top seems to be pretty dry, but I might be overwatering it since the pot is deep. The tree also hasn’t settled well, with the other soil in the pot and the roots. But it still seems strong and persistent, maybe it’s just starting to give out though?

Comment: Welcome! Could you please [edit] your post and include a few photos? It’s often easier if we can see the actual plant.

Comment: I don't suppose Pomegranate are like Persimmon trees and shed their leaves completely every year? Guessing not if it's a bonsai, but...